# Service Bus Topics and Incoming Messages

Tags: wcf, servicebus

I'm using NetMessagingBinding on a IIS hosted WCF service to consume messages published on a Windows Server Service Bus Topic.

From my understanding there is no limit on message size on Topics for Windows Server Service Bus, but nevertheless I'm getting an error deserializing a message from the subscription:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: (...) 
The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. 
This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.  
Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type [Type]. 
The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: 
The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.
```

The way i see it there is no configuration that i can change in WCF's web.config to change the maximum string content. The only property that could be related is MaxBufferPoolSize but it is not exposed through the web.config.

The binding configuration used is:

```
<bindings>
  <netMessagingBinding>
       <binding name="messagingBinding" 
                 closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00"
                 prefetchCount="-1" sessionIdleTimeout="00:01:00">
       <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:01" />
     </binding>
   </netMessagingBinding>
</bindings>
```

Thanks in advance,

Joao Carlos de Sousa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can also be solved by using a custom binding which uses the netMessagingTransport. This way the readerQuotas node can be use to define the reader quotas.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="sbBindingConfiguration" sendTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="100000000" maxStringContentLength="100000000" 
                    maxArrayLength="100000000" maxBytesPerRead="100000000" maxNameTableCharCount="100000000"/>
     </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <netMessagingTransport  manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="100000" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000">
        <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:00"/>
      </netMessagingTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363651/wcf-netmessagingbinding-and-outgoing-quotas) for more details on how to use the custom binding.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems like this is a WCF level error and not Service Bus. Have you tried to raise the MaxMessageSize? [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6ad1bf1c-e340-44ae-8ba5-91428d6e78a7/) has info on it, but basically, you need to setup something like the following on your binding's configuration in the web.config:

```
     <binding name="yourBinding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" 
             maxBufferSize="10000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
             maxArrayLength="100000000"
             maxStringContentLength="100000000"/>
    </binding>
```

Comment: After adding those configurations i got parser errors (e.g. Unrecognized attribute 'maxReceivedMessageSize'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.). Please note that I'm using "netMessagingBinding". Thanks Ramiro!

Answer (score 0):

NetMessagingBinding currently does not allow one to change the MaxStringContentLenght through the XML configuration.

A solution that worked for me was to create a message formatter behaviour extension by implementing the [IDispatchMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.aspx) interface.

The extension can then be used either by:

- creating an attribute that can be used in code to identify which operation contracts will use the message formatter behaviour

  ```
  public class MessageFormatterExtensionBehaviorAttribute : 
     Attribute, IOperationBehavior
  {

    (...)

  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
  {
      dispatchOperation.Formatter = new MessageFormatterExtension();
  }

  (...)

  }
  ```
- creating a [configuration element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.behaviorextensionelement.aspx) that exposes the custom behaviour.