# WCF NetMessagingBinding and Outgoing Quotas

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, servicebus

I'm trying to use WCF and NetMessagingBinding to publish messages into a Windows Service Service Bus Topic and for large messages - at least 603kb - the push operation is throwing the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for outgoing messages (262144) has been exceeded.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.BufferedOutputStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.FlushBuffer()
   at System.Xml.XmlStreamNodeWriter.GetBuffer(Int32 count, Int32& offset)
   at System.Xml.XmlStreamNodeWriter.UnsafeWriteUTF8Chars(Char* chars, Int32 charCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.UnsafeWriteText(Char* chars, Int32 charCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.WriteText(String value)
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseWriter.WriteString(String value)
   (...)
```

From the error I noticed that the problem is not the serialization and therefore I can't use a Message Formatter. What else can I use to overcome this exception? Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by replacing the netMessagingBinding by a customBinding which uses the netMessagingTransport.

1- Add netMessagingTransport as a binding extension:

```
   <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>
```

2- Add a custom binding:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="sbBindingConfiguration" sendTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="100000000" maxStringContentLength="100000000" 
                    maxArrayLength="100000000" maxBytesPerRead="100000000" maxNameTableCharCount="100000000"/>
     </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <netMessagingTransport  manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="100000" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000">
        <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:00"/>
      </netMessagingTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

3- Use the attribute maxReceivedMessageSize to define a value that suits the size of messages that will be exchanged

4- Reference your custom binding in the endpoint

```
<endpoint (...) binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="sbBindingConfiguration" />
```